# Vaadin Combo Box

Tags: drop-down-menu, vaadin

Am using vaadin application, a page having two combo box
1. Country 
2. States

based on country i want to populate states drop down value.
Using valuechangeevent i retrieved all states for the country how can i load to the states drop down.

Pls help me :)

Answer (score 4):

Below sample code may help you implement what you want

```
AbstractOrderedLayout outerLayout = new VerticalLayout();
final Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stateList.add("state1");
        stateList.add("state2");
        stateList.add("state3");

        map.put("USA", stateList);
        final ComboBox country = new ComboBox("country",map.keySet());
        country.setImmediate(true);
        outerLayout.addComponent(country);

        country.addListener(new Property.ValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void valueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
                ComboBox stateComboBox = new ComboBox("state",map.get(country.getValue().toString()));

                outerLayout.addComponent(stateComboBox);
            }
        });
```